# Why do i get error in where clause on update mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm getting an error about `Unknown column 'CR0001' in 'where clause'` and I don't know why because the where clause it's about id_scooter column not cr0001. Here is my code

```
var update = "UPDATE  coordonate SET ? WHERE id_scooter=CR0001 "; 
    con.query(update, { id_scooter: array[0], lat: array[3], longi: array[4], alt: array[5], ip: rinfo.address, port: rinfo.port, speed: array[6], nr_satelites: array[2], battery_lvl: array[1] }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
});
```

Comment: `CR0001` isn't enclosed in quotes `''` so it is seen as a column identifier instead of as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR0001 is a string, not an integer. Therefore it has to be in quotes like this:

```
var update = "UPDATE  coordonate SET ? WHERE id_scooter='CR0001' ";
```

If you want custom parameters in your ? question marks, you can pass array as second argument:

```
var update = "UPDATE  coordonate SET ?=? WHERE id_scooter=? "; 
con.query(update, [col, val, idscooter], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
});
```

(Replace col, val, idscooter with correct data)

Comment: true, and if want to change SET ? where ? and move the column  on query list how should I do?

Comment: Updated in answer.

Comment: I get unexpected token if I add array[0] at the end `con.query(update, { id_scooter: array[0], lat: array[3], longi: array[4], alt: array[5], ip: rinfo.address, port: rinfo.port, speed: array[6], nr_satelites: array[2], battery_lvl: array[1],array[0] }, function (err, result) {
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['`

Comment: As I explained in my answer. You need to replace your whole object with correct data structure which will correspond to ? question marks. You can't just add array[0] at the end of object. Replace whole object with new array and put there 3 fields with correct data. If you don't know how to do it, there is nothing I can do here :( Remove { id_scooter: array[0], lat: array[3], longi: array[4], alt: array[5], ip: rinfo.address, port: rinfo.port, speed: array[6], nr_satelites: array[2], battery_lvl: array[1],array[0] } Put there [col, val, idscooter] these 3 variables has to have data